# uWSGI emperor mongodb config

Tags: mongodb, uwsgi

we're trying to configure an uWSGI emperor and workers using a mongodb collection.

Here is how the collection looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("533de5c835a024e0578d6675"),
    "harakiri-verbose" : true,
    "limit-post" : 65536,
    "stats" : "/path/to/file.socket",
    "log-slow" : true,
    "ts" : ISODate("2014-04-03T22:50:35.464Z"),
    "buffer-size" : 65535,
    "post-buffering" : 1048576,
    "master" : true,
    "show-config" : true,
    "env" : "LANG:en_US.UTF-8",
    "config" : "junx_1",
    "pidfile" : "/path/to/file.pid",
    "listen" : 100,
    "auto-procname" : true,
    "vassal_id" : "1",
    "harakiri" : 7200,
    "vacuum" : true,
    "no-orphans" : true,
    "name" : "appname",
    "processes" : 4,
    "procname-prefix-spaced" : "app_worker",
    "socket" : "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:0",
    "plugin" : "php",
    "enabled" : 1,
    "reload-on-rss" : 300,
    "binary-path" : "/home/uwsgi/uwsgi",
    "subscribe2" : "server:xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1010,key:xx.xxx.xxx.xxx,modifier1:14,sign:SHA1:/home/uwsgi_keys/private.pem",
    "max-requests" : 10000,
    "daemonize" : "/var/log/uwsgi/app.log"
}
```

here's the emperor command output:

```
/uwsgi --emperor mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017,emperor.vassals,{enabled:1} --plugin emperor_mongodb --show-config

;uWSGI instance configuration
[uwsgi]
emperor = mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017,emperor.vassals,{enabled:1}
plugin = emperor_mongodb
show-config = true
;end of configuration

*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.3 (64bit) on [Fri Apr  4 01:17:51 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 03 April 2014 23:53:12
os: Linux-3.10.23-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 18 14:48:24 CET 2014
nodename: {nodename}
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 40
current working directory: /home/uwsgi
detected binary path: /home/uwsgi/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 2063402
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
[emperor] enabled emperor MongoDB monitor for 127.0.0.1:27017 on collection emperor.vassals
*** starting uWSGI Emperor ***
```

the emperor works fine with the mongo collection, queries all documents with `{"enabled": 1}` however no workers are started.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

We solved the problem by giving the `collection.name` a valid `extension`: `emperor.vassals.name = appname` => `emperor.vassals.name = appname.json`